# AWS Cloudformation cfn-init not installing packages

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to get a simple AWS Cloudformation **cfn-init** script working but not having any success. The script is shown below. When I log in to the instance created, httpd isn't even installed. I'm creating an AWS Linux2 instance in us-east-1.

```
Resources:
  ...
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata: 
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init: 
        config: 
          packages: 
            yum:
              httpd: []
          files:
            /var/www/html/index.html:
              content: !Sub |
                <html><body>Hello, World</body></html>
          services: 
            sysvinit:
              httpd:
                enabled: true
                ensureRunning: true
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: ami-0323c3dd2da7fb37d
      KeyName: KeyPair
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:                                
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
            yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource Ec2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}
```

Comment: Any chance you first created the instance, and then added the cfn-init configuration/UserData as an update to the already running instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deployed your template, and can **confirm it is correct**. `httpd` and `index.html` are installed and deployed as expected.

There must be something else happening. For example, deploying to a private subnet without internet. In that case httpd want be installed. Or like @Christian mentioned, amending existing instance.

Comment: thanks. Yes, the template does work. As best I can tell it's something to do with the Security Group. The template that didn't work also creates the SG. But when I assign an existing SG, it works.